# How Do I Make a Float Have Exactly 8 Digits?

Tags: php

So, say I have the numbers 1.234567891011 and 12.34567891011. Is there any way for me to be able to round both numbers in such a way that only eight digits are included in both numbers without knowing them in advanced? I know I can:

```
round($num1, 7);
round($num2, 6);
```

But I am looking for a way to round in such a way that, regardless of the length of the whole part, the rounding methodology leaves me with numbers exactly 8 digits long.

Comment: including non decimal number?

Comment: Yes. Including the number before the decimal point.

Comment: So the result you want is the numbers formatted as `1.2345678` and `12.345678`, correct?

Comment: That is correct. I want to do it in such a way that it works with all numbers.

Comment: where are your trials? the precision has gotta be a variable. so get the number of digits before the decimal point. and use that as reference, by the way. what if this happens? `41,200,300.50`?

Comment: example in 12.34567891011 , so you want get this value 12.345678 ?

Comment: You can't fully control this with floats. You will need to convert to a string at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to *truncate* your numbers to exactly 8 digits (not counting the decimal point):

```php
function myTrunc( $n ) {
    $first9 = substr( $n, 0, 9 ); // The first 9 chars
    $hasDecimal = ( FALSE !== strpos( $first9, '.' ) ); // Whether it contains a decimal
    $r = substr( $first9, 0, $hasDecimal ? 9 : 8 ); // Get first 8 (or 9 if there is a decimal)
    return trim( $r, '.' ); // Trim any trailing decimal (so 12345678. becomes 12345678)
}

$n1 = 1.234567891011;
$n2 = 12.34567891011;
$n3 = 1234567891011;
$n4 = 1234567.891011;
$n5 = 12345678.91011;
$n6 = 123456789.1011;

echo "$n1 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n1 ) . "\n"; // 1.2345678
echo "$n2 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n2 ) . "\n"; // 12.345678
echo "$n3 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n3 ) . "\n"; // 12345678
echo "$n4 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n4 ) . "\n"; // 1234567.8
echo "$n5 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n5 ) . "\n"; // 12345678
echo "$n6 truncates to " . myTrunc( $n6 ) . "\n"; // 12345678
```